# Prove that if sequence does not tend to infinity, then it has a bounded subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinity

I need to prove that that if sequence does not tend to infinity, then it has a bounded subsequence. I have tried to divide my problem into 2 subcases. 1) when my sequence is bounded, by Bolzano-Weierstrass I can prove that it has a bounded subsequence. 2) when my sequence is unbounded, it also has 2 subcases. I do contradiction and assume that there is no subsequence which is bounded. Either my subseqences tend to infinity or they do not have a limit. I'm stuck at this point. What would you suggest to do next?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofb28.jpg)

Comment: Just a comment on the first case: if your sequence is bounded then every subsequence is bounded, including itself. You definitely don't need Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks

Comment: I would try writing down the negation of the definition of convergence to infinity. You will see that you don't need cases here.

Comment: The sequence $\;\{(-1)^nn\}\;$ doesn't tend to infinity (it has no limit at all, either finite or generalized), yet it has no bounded subsequence...

Comment: @DonAntonio I was assuming this means $\forall M$, there exists $N$ s.t. $n>N$ implies $|a_n|>|M|$, in which case you just apply the converse. But I agree that this is not the usual definition of "converging to $\infty$"

Comment: Is there any other approach that could work? I guess mine is not working.

Comment: Note your negation is incorrect...

Comment: in what part of the negation is the mistake?

Comment: The correct negation of "for every $M > 0$, we have $|x_n| > M$ for all except finitely many $n$" is: "there exists an $M > 0$ such that $|x_n| \leq M$ for infinitely many $n$".

Comment: Or a little closer to what you've written, the negation of $$\forall M \exists n_0 \forall n (n \geq n_0 \implies |a_n| > M$$ is $$\exists M \forall n_0 \exists n (n\geq n_0 \land |a_n|\leq M)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it is useless to divide the problem in these two subcases because if sequence is bounded obviously it has bounded subsequence (it itself is its own sub-sequence).

I suggest a solution: let's assume that there is sequence $(a_n)$ which does not tend to infinity. It means that the following is not true:

$$\forall N > 0\, \exists n: \forall k > n \, |a_k| > N.$$

The opposite of the logical expression is
$$\exists N > 0\, \forall n: \exists k > n \, |a_k| \leq N.$$
Let's construct bounded subsequence. We will fix the $N$ from expression and for the first element one can take $a_{k_1}$ such that $k_1 > 1,|a_{k_1}| \leq N$ (indeed it exists because one can put 1 instead of $n$ in expression $\exists N > 0\, \forall n: \exists k > n \, |a_k| \leq N$). For the next term we will get $a_{k_2}$ such that $k_2>k_1,a_{k_2} \leq N$. Continuing the process we will have bounded subsequence.

Comment: You haven't excluded the possibility that this subsequence is unbounded below (converges to $-\infty$).

Comment: Oh thanks! I will fix it.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much!